# changing the color of a bootstrap caret (on hover of the first "li" element)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, caret

So basically, I can't seem to change the color of the caret above my dropdown during the hover of the first-child element.

I am using Bootstrap3, the dropdown code is below:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o71qdh3L/)

**Nav dropdown**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Drop1 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Drop2 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Anyway, I want the caret on top to be colored on hover for the first-child "li" element:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhw5P.png)

Any ideas on how to change the color of the caret when the first element is hovered over?

Comment: The desktop version is at: fiddle.jshell.net/o71qdh3L/show/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that with just CSS. You have two options I think.. The ugly one - use JavaScript, or you can change the location of the carret to sit inside first element, then:

```
.dropdown-menu li:first-child:hover:after {...}
```

Comment: I tried this, but you when you hover only on the caret, it goes active and the first link becomes inactive.